# assumable role iam policy with conditions for aws:RequestTag and sts:SourceIdentity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sts

I want to create the role (that will be assumed by another IAM role) with the following policy:

I should be able to assume the role only:

- if tag team is set to "team"
- if tag department is set to "devops"
- if user set source identity when assuming the role

I'm failing with the following error:

```bash
aws sts assume-role \
  --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::1111122222333:role/team-sso-administrators-role" \
  --role-session-name JimSmith \
  --source-identity JimSmith \
  --tags Key=team,Value=team Key=department,Value=devops

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::ANOTHERACCOUNTID:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_team-administrators-role_feadc200cc9855b0/JimSmith is not authorized to perform: sts:SetSourceIdentity on resource: arn:aws:iam::1111122222333:role/team-sso-administrators-role
```

#### the statement of the policy

```
statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole", "sts:SetSourceIdentity", "sts:TagSession"] # 
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = var.trusted_role_arns
    }
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = var.trusted_role_services
    }    
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:RequestTag/department"
      values  = ["devops"]
    }
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:RequestTag/team"
      values  = ["team"]
    }
    condition {
      test = "StringLike"
      variable = "sts:SourceIdentity"
      values = ["*"]
    }
    
    condition {
      test     = "ForAllValues:StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:TagKeys"
      values  = ["department", "team"]
    }
```

If I remove "sts:SetSourceIdentity" and associated condition - I can enforce tags
If I remove "sts:TagSession" and associated conditions - I can enforce SourceIdentity

#### So how to combine together?